# Python: Cx_Freeze FileNotFoundError: Errno 2 in library.zip

Tags: python-3.x, csv, cx-freeze, setup.py, file-not-found

I want to build my python script with Cx_Freeze, however i get this error :

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'C:\Users\...\build\exe.win323.8\lib\library.zip/table.csv' does not exist: b'C:\Users\...\build\exe.win32-3.8\lib\library.zip/table.csv'

My setup.py is :

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
includefiles = ['table.csv']
zipincludes = ['table.csv']
# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [], include_files = includefiles, zip_includes = zipincludes)
include_package_data=True
base = 'Console'

executables = [
    Executable('ReportGenerator.py', base=base, targetName = 'report_generator')
]

setup(
    name='test13',
    version = '1.0',
    description = 'test13',
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
    executables = executables)
```

I use python 38.
pip 19.3.1
I don't undertand why it can't find my csv.
I have the file .csv on the good zip :
[file.csv in library.zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNUZM.png)

Thanks